# Spliting list till finding an element

Tags: python, list

I'm reading a file that has lines like these:

```
2SomethingHere
3Whatever
3Whatever 
4foo
4bar
5baz
2SomethingHere
3Whatever
3Whatever 
4foo
4bar
5baz
```

This is a test file, and I've been reading like:

```
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
contents = file.readlines()
```

In order to separate lines and getting them into a list. But I want to separate this list into a list of lists like this:

```
main_list = [['2SomethingHere', '3Whatever', '3Whatever', '4foo', '4baz', '5baz'], ['2SomethingHere', '3Whatever', '3Whatever', '4foo', '4baz', '5baz']]
```

Being `2` at the beggining of one element the start of a new list.

I've been trying this:

```
from itertools import groupby
result = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(contents,lambda x:x.startswith('2')) if k]
```

But the result is showing only the elements starting with `2`

I want all the elements following this `2` until finding another.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: try this, ```[x.splitlines() for x in contents.split(contents[0]) if x]```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the file will start with a `2` on the first line, then you can just do:

```
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
contents = file.readlines()

print(contents)

main_list = []
for el in contents:
    if el.startswith("2"):
        main_list.append([])  # add a new sub-list
    main_list[-1].append(el.strip())  # add line (without leading/trailing whitespace) to the last sub-list

print(main_list)
```

but if it might not, then you would have to do something like:

```
main_list = [[]]
for el in contents:
    if el.startswith("2") and main_list[-1]:
        main_list.append([])
    main_list[-1].append(el.strip())
```

so that the start is handled a little bit differently: an initial sublist is already present ready for the items, even if the first line does not start with `"2"`, but if the first line *does* start with 2, then it does not immediately move onto a new sub-list (which would leave an empty sub-list at the start of the output).

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to group the lines by the first character then:

```
import itertools

with open("test.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

groups = itertools.groupby(lines, key=lambda line: line[:1])
results = [list(g) for k, g in groups if k]
print(results)
```

Comment: This is useful, but its not what I need... I want to group the lines in a way that if the line starts with 2 take all the following lines until finding another line starting with 2, then it creates other list with those elements...

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Check how I achieved that [here](https://repl.it/repls/PleasantLankyKilobyte)